# Integrate smart contract on backend (without metamask and wallet signing transaction)

Tags: transactions, metamask, dapps, dapp-development, nodejs

i have a working dapp on frontend **sending transactions and signing them through connected wallet (*metamask*)**.

I want to transfert this logic of sending transactions to my backend (nodejs).

**so there will be no signing transactions nor metamask.**

how can i do that ?

Answer (score 2):

Hi dev advocate at [Chainstack](https://chainstack.com/) here!

The best way will be to use a web3 library; I recommend [web3.js](https://github.com/ChainSafe/web3.js) if you want to work in JavaScript.

Remember that you still need to sign the transactions with your private key; it's just done programmatically instead of using the MetaMask front-end.

The following is the basic code to create and send a transaction using web3.js.

```js
var Web3 = require('web3');
var node_URL = 'CHAINSTACK_NODE_URL';
var web3 = new Web3(node_URL);
var Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx').Transaction;

// Logic of this code:
    // Set the addresses and private key to sign the transaction
    // Build transaction 
    // Sign and send the transaction 

// Addresses and private key
const sender = "SENDER_ADDRESS";
const receiver = "RECEIVER_ADDRESS";
const private_key = Buffer.from('PRIVATE_KEY', "hex"); 

// Build the transaction
web3.eth.getTransactionCount(sender, (err, transactionCount) => {
    const transaction_Object = {
        to: receiver,
        gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei("20", "gwei")),
        gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(21000),
        nonce: web3.utils.toHex(transactionCount),
        value: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei("0.5", "ether")),
    };

    // Signing the transaction 

    // create a new transaction object to sign 
    const tx = new Tx(transaction_Object, {
        chain: "ropsten"
    });

    // sign the transaction using the private key  
    tx.sign(private_key);

    //   Send signed transaction to the blockchain 
    const sTx = tx.serialize();
    const rawTransaction = "0x" + sTx.toString("hex");

    web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(rawTransaction, (err, hash) => {
        console.log("TxHash:" + hash);
        console.log(err);
    });
})
```

This is the code to send a transaction from an account to another. You will find more code examples on the [Node API reference page](https://docs.chainstack.com/api/node-api-reference).

Answer (score 0):

you could get network access via alchemy or Infura and create and sign transactions using a framework like ethers.js or web3.js